# Асинхронность в .Net Core 3

Tags: .net-core, async-await

На мой API от стороннего приложения поступают запросы на создание приема к врачу. Метод который создает приемы - асинхронный. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно избежать ситуации когда n-ое кол-во пациентов пытается записаться на одно время? Т.е. на одно время записаться может только один пациент.

Comment: Метод возвращает модель созданного приема на стороннее приложение

Comment: Что используете для работы с БД? В документации по используемой технологии всегда есть разделы наподобие [Optimistic Concurrency](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency) ADO.NET или [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

По идее в момент мохранения записи в БД должна произойти ошибка с нарушением уникального ключа, ну а в случае такой ошибки пользователю тоже надо послать ошибку что время уже занято.

Comment: @Jack Так уникальный ключ должен быть на комбинацию полей - время и врач или что-то такое

Comment: @Jack, уникальный ключ - это время и кабинет. Можно делать время и врач, но мне кажется, с кабинетом лучше.